# Find deleted element in Array

Tags: javascript

I need to find the first available deleted slot in the Array

This works:

```
var A = [1,2]
A[0] = undefined
console.log(A.indexOf(undefined))
```

But how about this?:

```
var A = [1,2]
delete A[0]
console.log(A)
console.log(A.indexOf(null)) ???
```

Comment: Seems like an XY problem. Using a sparse array is probably not the right solution for your problem. What is the goal, what are you trying to do?

Comment: `function removeFromArray(arr, index) {
    delete arr[0];
    return index;
};` ?

Comment: @elclanrs, `undefined` is fine for me, I was just curious if I can use empty slots as well. Also sparse array can save some memory in certain circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the array looking for keys not present.

```
function find_first_empty_slot(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (!(i in arr)) { return i; }
    }
    return -1;
 }
```

You cannot find these using `indexOf`, because it does not look at missing elements. You can also not use `Array#forEach` etc. because they skip over the missing elements.

Comment: I also think you have to look in the array if you want to do it with "empty slots"